# How to invert fn keys on Dell Laptop?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell

My Dell laptop (XPS 15z) has special keys on the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys. If I want to disable keyboard backlight, for example, I must type <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.

- Is it possible to invert it?

In fact, I don't often use the <kbd>F*</kbd> keys.

- How can I only hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to disable the backlight and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to type <kbd>F6</kbd>?
- Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: People here I recommend going to the top voted answer not the accepted answer. It is much easier to do ctrl-esc than to mess around in bios. FYI.

Comment: I updated the accepted answer.

Comment: You can switch behaviour of function keys (to function with or without Fn key).. use Fn + Esc (fn padlock icon icon)

Answer (score 414, accepted):

I am not sure if it works for all models, but on mine if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> it changes the `Fn lock` so that <kbd>F1</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> work as normal and when you hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>+(lets say <kbd>F11</kbd>) it will change the brightness or whatever that keys secondary function is. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> again reverts it back to default. Hope this helps.

Comment: Gah, thank you for posting this! I accidentally pressed this without even realizing such a feature exists. Would go hunting around BIOS if you hadn't helped!

Comment: Wow that is an awful default toggle to have on a row that is so similar to the intended row.  Why this isn't the accepted answer is a rare glitch in the SO matrix.

Comment: This is a better answer as it is an easier option. Wondering why this is not marked as answer!

Comment: I always did it changing BIOS but didn't found this option in my new notebook. `Fn+Esc` worked, to be honest `Esc` even has a padlock icon but I was unable to figure out alone.

Comment: Did not work on HP tre -1025

Comment: Works on Lenovo.

Comment: Fabulous!! I was messing about with keyboard shortcuts for a long time trying to get my Intellij code editor to work. Fn + Esc was the solution, and effortless to implement!

Comment: Pressing Function Key + Shift make it inverted in HP EliteBook Laptop

Comment: On my keyboard, the Esc key has a tiny little padlock symbol with 'Fn' in it. But not something you'd actually notice, nor even somewhere you'd think to look.

Comment: Thanks, this would never occur to me.. I thought the lock icon on the `ESC` means a screen lock and that it just doesn't work lol. Anyway, I'll just add I had this issue with desktop keyboard Dell KB216t and this solved the issue. Hopefully this'll make it easier to find this answer via Google for ppl with the same keyboard (most of the questions about this are for laptops and the solutions don't necessarily apply to desktops).

Comment: Thanks it worked on my dell laptop on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is not specific to Ubuntu. It should work on any operating system (at least works on Windows 11).

Comment: Works on Apple Magic Keyboard

Answer (score 62):

It should be possible to do it in the BIOS. Quoting the XPS 15z manual:

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> during POST (Power On Self Test) to enter the System Setup (BIOS) utility.
2. In the Function Key Behavior, select Multimedia Key First or Function Key First.

   - Function Key First — This is the default option. Press any function key to perform the
     associated function. For multimedia action, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + the required multimedia key.
   - Multimedia Key First — Press any multimedia key to perform the associated multimedia action.
     For function, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + the required function key.

Comment: This works for a different model Dell laptop I have as well, and I would suspect for anything else with Dell's BIOS (don't have experience with any other vendors).

Comment: This also works for my Lenovo (Flex 2) Laptop.  No 2 options as mentioned above, just an `enable` and `disable` option.

Comment: On a new Dell XPS 13, the option is under "POST Behavior", "Fn Lock Options"

Comment: If enabled in the BIOS (which I assume it is by default), you can toggle the behavior of the Fn key with the Fn+Esc hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

On mine, the problem was that the NumLk key had been pressed. Pressing it again holding the Fn key reverted the Fn key back.

Comment: This works for my laptop only 1 time (1 F-key click) after pressing and loding NumLk+Fn. Then it does not work again.