# How to invert Fn keys?

Tags: 16.04, bios

Is there a way to invert the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in Ubuntu 16.04?

I tried this but my BIOS does not have change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> Keys.

[How to invert fn keys on Dell Laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88063/how-to-invert-fn-keys-on-dell-laptop)

I have a Clevo N131BU laptop with American Megatrends Bios.

Comment: I think it is BIOS issue, not Ubuntu. Try harder to find such option in the BIOS.

Comment: I look again and there's nothing. Maybe I need to find a way to unlock my BIOS.