# F3-F6 behave like media keys. How do I disable media keys entirely?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, keyboard-layout

Under both regular Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04, I can no longer use my <kbd>F3</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> keys, because they have been stolen by media keys.

This is NOT a laptop. I don't have any media keys on my keyboard, nor do I have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> select key. I don't want media keys. I want my <kbd>F3</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> keys back.

Keyboard is a Kinesis Advantage MPC/USB ergonomic keyboard. Workstation is a Dell Precision T7600.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88063/how-to-invert-fn-keys-on-dell-laptop

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but unfortunately it doesn't apply, as my keyboard does not have a Function select key. It does not have alternate functions at all.